# Chattering error during simulation of a model with using "when" as control condition

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I try to control the volume of a tank, but the simulation chatters after 8 s.

This is the control model which is used to control the valves:

```
model CONTROLLER

  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput V_min;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput V_max;
  Modelica.Blocks.Interfaces.RealInput V;
  Boolean open1(start=true), open2(start=false);

equation 

  when V > V_min then
    open1 = true;
  elsewhen V <= V_min then
    open1 = false;
  end when;

  open2 = not open1;

end CONTROLLER;
```

Comment: Can you use a hysteresis? https://www.google.com/search?q=site:mbe.modelica.university+chattering

Answer (score 3):

If you use the same threshold to open and close the valves, chattering is the obvious result.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53631256/8725275) and [Modelica by Example](https://mbe.modelica.university/behavior/discrete/decay/#chattering), which both describe very good what chattering is and how it can be avoided.

Comment: i tried to use hysteresis but i get results but no results when the state of the boolean changer (open1=false,open2=true) ,i get this error msg                                                                
 the error msg:                                                                                                                        
 85.3439s time of jacobian evaluation
free mixed system solvers
free non-linear system solvers
Simulation process failed. Exited with code -11.

Comment: now i get some resaltuts after boolean state changes but just for melli_seconds and i get a new erro sayin" DSKR BECAUSE IRES WAS EQUAL TO MINUS ONE"  , what is the cause of this please

Comment: It seems like you are using OpenModelica. I added the relevant tag, so one of the experts might help. But I would recommend to ask a new question with a minimal example. With the current info it is quite hard to help. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask when you do that - especially the section 'Help others reproduce the problem'.

Comment: thank you very much ,am new in stackoverflow ,thats why am facing problems with writing a post

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
when abs(V - V_min) > 1.E-5 then 
  open = not pre(open);
end when;
```

This is a when condition that triggers both ways, but has a small tolerance. You have to initialize the variable `open(start = false)` to make sure it works as intended.

If the surrounding system reacts to this change slowly it does not cause chattering, if this directly influences `der(V)` it slows the simulation down and may still break.

For good handling of such switches i recommend looking at `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Ideal.IdealDiode` (extends from `Modelica.Electrical.Analog.Interfaces.IdealSemiconductor`) which represents an ideal diode. As you might see it is not really the model of a truly ideal diode, but it is as simplified as it can be without causing chattering.