# Dymola: Valve Regulation on/off Function

Tags: fluid, modelica, dymola

How can I set the valve closed when the hot water tank temperature/temperature sensor *SenTem* >= 70 Celsius?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways this could be done. The most obvious way would be using

- `Modelica.Blocks.Logical.GreaterThreshold`
- combined with `Modelica.Blocks.Math.BooleanToReal`

but this will likely result in [chattering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58894882/chattering-error-during-simulation-of-a-model-with-using-when-as-control-condi).

It should be possible to avoid this by using a hysteresis block instead of the simple comparison

- `Modelica.Blocks.Logical.Hysteresis`

which is used e.g. here: `Modelica.Fluid.Examples.Tanks.TanksWithOverflow`, where a switch is applied instead of the `BooleanToReal`. The advantage here is, that you can manually define the two output values (e.g. in case you don't want to fully open the valve).

There is also a dedicated "controller" that should do what you need

- `Modelica.Blocks.Logical.OnOffController`

An example using the controller can be found here: `Modelica.Thermal.HeatTransfer.Examples.ControlledTemperature`. It should behave very similar to the hysteresis block, using different parameters.